# Problem with Spring Actuator metrics without @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

In my Springboot-based app I cannot use `@EnableAutoConfiguration` therefore I must add all configurations manually to `@Import` annotation. I know how to enable general endpoint `/actuator` and some others like `/actuator/health` or `/actuator/env` (example below). However even though I tried thousands options I cannot make `metrics` working (with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` it works).
My config is as follows:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
@Import({
        ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,

        ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        EnvironmentEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        //---------- configs metrics related: 
        MetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class,
        JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class
}
)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

With such config even though I can see `metrics` endpoint listed on `/actuator` page:
[actuator main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X15oV.png)

if I go there it it shows empty collection:
[no metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBNDK.png)

And it should contain system and jvm metrics (and http endpoints metrics after first http call).
Any idea what I should do in order to enable Spring Actuator metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, the order of metrics imports was incorrect, the order should be as follows:

```
        MetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class,
        CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class,
        JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class
```

Comment: Shouldn't auto configurations be imported using `ImportAutoConfiguration` rather than `Import`?